# In ReactJS , radio button rendering

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a POC for my project. I am using React for front end.
I am pretty new to reactjs. I have a small query can someone help me.

I am getting json data from the server, the data is as below:

```
{
   [id: 1,
   name: Test data,
   option:{ "numeric", "alpha-numeric", "special characters", "language change" ] ....}
}
```

I need to display the options as radio buttons on my page so user can select and go to next  page. In the next page I get another set of data for option which need to be displayed as radio buttons. 
How should I build this generic radio button component in reactjs so I could use across all the pages in my application.

I have tried this code. But it prints the radio button on a single line. Loop is not working

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { PageHeader, ListGroup } from "react-bootstrap";

import "./Home.css";

const url = "http://localhost:xxxx/rest/qas/2";

export default class Question3 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      selectedOption: false,
      QuestionAnswer: [],
      counter: 0,
      names: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);

        return response.json();
      })
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          qid: json.qid,
          qtext: json.qtext,
          point: json.marks,
          ans: json.answer,
          choices: JSON.stringify(json.options)
        });
      });
  }

  // Note: it's important to handle errors here
  // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
  // exceptions from actual bugs in components.

  handleNext = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push("/question4");
  };

  handlePrevious = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push("/question2");
  };

  handleOptionChange = e => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      console.log(e.target.value);
      if (e.target.value === this.state.answer) this.props.counter += 1;
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { qid, qtext, point, ans } = this.state;

    const data = {
      option: [this.state.choices]
    };

    let radioButtons = [];

    const RadioButtons = props => {
      const { names } = props;

      return (
        <div>
          {" "}
          {names.map(n => (
            <Radio name={n} />
          ))}{" "}
        </div>
      );
    };

    const Radio = props => {
      const { name } = props;
      return (
        <div>
          <input id={name} type="radio" name="type" value={name} />{" "}
          <label for={name}> {name} </label>{" "}
        </div>
      );
    };

    //const listItems = replies.map((number) =>
    //  {number}
    //);

    return (
      <div className="q2">
        <div className="labels">
          <label for="test">
            {" "}
            {this.state.qid} {this.state.qtext}{" "}
          </label>{" "}
        </div>
        <div className="App">
          <RadioButtons names={data.option} />{" "}
        </div>
        <div className="Navigation">
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="btn btn-primary"
            onClick={this.handleNext}
          >
            Next{" "}
          </button>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{" "}
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="btn btn-primary"
            onClick={this.handlePrevious}
          >
            Previous{" "}
          </button>{" "}
        </div>{" "}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `But it prints the radio button on a single line.Loop is not working`. Share the screenshot of what is wrong and how do you want it. How are we supposed to know that ? Also, I've provided you with the minimal answer which will work absolutely fine if the data you pass is correct.

Comment: Ok.I will check and revert.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pretty generic question but I'll try to answer as best as I can without just giving you the full code.

The data you get from the server will be used to generate the RadioButtons, so you will need to store that in state/redux/localstorage or w/e else you choose to store it in. Once you have that down you will need to create a component that can then be REUSED through the app. There are plenty of examples out there of components so I wont get into that. In your component you will then need to access the data you have stored from the API. For this example I'm gonna assume you have the data stored in a `const` and passing it down to the component as a prop: `<RadioButtons names={data.options} />`

In the RadioButtons component you can take the prop in the render of the component loop through it to render the buttons:

```
render() {
    let radioButtons = [];
    this.props.names.map(name => radioButtons.push(<input type="radio" value={name}> {name} <br>));
    return <div>{radioButtons}</div>;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example of what you can do.

`RadioButtons` is a component that take `names` as a prop which then maps over it to return a list of `Radio` components. `Radio` component is responsible for consuming the `name` prop and rendering a single radio button with a label. Also, remember to keep the `type` of the radio button same if you want only one selection.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const data = {
  name: "Test data",
  option: ["numeric", "alpha-numeric", "special characters", "language change"]
};

const RadioButtons = props => {
  const { names } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      {names.map(n => (
        <Radio name={n} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Radio = props => {
  const { name } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <input id={name} type="radio" name="type" value={name} />
      <label for={name}>{name}</label>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RadioButtons names={data.option} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding !

Comment: i have posted my code above. it seems to give radio button in a single line.Can you help

Comment: @Jaya lol you answered your own question....edit your question rather than answering

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question. Could you help please